# showing a validation error message when providing invalid input in simple_form in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, simple-form

for a simple MVC app in ruby on rails I have a model set up:

model:

```
class Cake < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :doses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :dose

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

in the new view I have this simple form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @cake do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.input :photo %> 
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

How do I through a specific error message? E.g. "name already exists" when name validation is not passed

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake: Simple Form handles error messaging automatically if I use f.input (instead of f.label and f.text_field)

this code worked for me:

```
<%= simple_form_for @cake do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :photo %> 
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```